# Option of Deleting an Account

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

There, MATH.SE is progressing nicely, but i think there are certain things which can be adopted. Since many people have *strange opinions* and are not comfortable with my behavior , i feel like getting out of here. Once, i had this thought, the next thing which i felt asking was:

- MATH.SE allows us to create an account. Similarly, why not enable the option of *deleting* an account, permanently. This feature has been adopted by many public websites like the Orkut, Facebook, Etc.

Comment: This would be a good feature.  As for the strange opinions, thick skin is advisable. Post and be merry:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/632/add-se-is-not-a-social-networking-site    .  Focusing attention on an individual user is an admission that the rating and reputation system (in its current form) does not help so much in filtering content.  Disclosure of additional metrics such as ratio of up- to down-votes, or answer-votes to question-votes, would handle these things much better than debating the merits of particular users.

Comment: @T.. Thanks for the comment T..! May i ask you one thing! Why is ur name T..

Comment: Because I was T. (one dot) on MathOverflow when I heard about math.SE, but on the SE 2.0 sites the user names require at least three characters.

Comment: ha ha .... nice imagination

Comment: @T..: I really don't want to depress others by my behavior, so i shall try my best not to post a question.

Comment: @T.. Since this site is growing there are lot of useless questions, coming up, which one by seeing *don't even want to answer it*. I guess, i was not a bad problem poser after all.

Comment: @T.. In your opinion, if there was *certain things which i could improve upon then what would that be?*

Comment: I may be the wrong person to ask, since for my purposes the only defect in your postings was that it was often hard to determine the source (a web search would have found something for many of those problems) or the difficulty level (I searched for one of the source-less problems recently and it was a hard question #3 from an International Mathematical Olympiad!).  It is easy to repair by adding some extra information to any given posting.  Beyond that, the degree of personal focus on one user is, in my opinion, horrible for the site.  "Make technology, not war."

Comment: To put it differently, if postings X or Y are a problem, I think one should identify the (objective) attributes of X and Y that are bad -- and even better, the attributes of non-XY that are good -- and have ways to promote the postings with good attributes.  Concentrating on one or more users who are sources of type X postings is senseless and distracts from developing the site.  I don't want to see users punished for posting unsourced or deceptively difficult material -- I want tools for upgrading sources and indicating the difficulty for ALL questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account)

> How to delete your account:
>
> 1. **Edit your profile to say "please delete me"** so we can confirm your ownership of the account.
> 2. **Obtain your user page URL or numeric user ID**. This is linked from the top of every page of the site, when you are logged in.
> 3. **Email the support address linked at the bottom of every web page** on the site. Where it says "contact us", click that. In your email, you **MUST** include your user page URL or user ID so we can find your account.

Comment: So what happens to the questions+answers belonging to the deleted user?

Comment: @Douglas: Those with negative vote count are deleted, while the others are unaffected.  (I know you asked over a year ago, but I figured an answer here might help future browsers.)

Comment: "Email the support address linked at the bottom of every web page on the site." This support address doesn't exist (any more). So how can I delete amy account?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/contact/user-deletion